# OnClick only image2 changes

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, android-imageview

In this, I want to change the images in the order. i.e on 1st click of dice1 itself, dice1 should change then dice2, dice3, dice4, and then again dice1 and soo on till the end of the loop. but whenever I click any image only the image in dice2 changes. The image I click only that should change that too in the predefined order. Can someone please help fix the code.

JAVA FILE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private ImageView dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4;
private ImageView[] dice = { dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4 };
private Random rng = new Random();
public int i=0,j=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dice[0] = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    dice[1]= findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    dice[2] = findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    dice[3] = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

    while(j<5){
        if(i==4){
            i=0;}
    dice[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rollDice();
        }
    });
    j++;
    i++;
    }
}

private void rollDice(){
    int randomNo = rng.nextInt(6)+1;

    switch (randomNo){
        case 1:
            dice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            break;
        case 2:
            dice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
            break;
        case 3:
            dice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
            break;
        case 4:
            dice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
            break;
        case 5:
            dice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            break;
        case 6:
            dice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your request is not clear enough, when you hit any image, then you want to change all the images to the dice number right?

Comment: No, when I hit some image only that image should change i.e only the dice I click should roll. then the next dice is clicked and then next and so on. Just like the game of ludo. But in my case, only one image changes irrespective of the fact whatever image I click on. Please help.